# Node CI being cancelled with no reason - GitHub Actions

Tags: node.js, vue.js, continuous-integration, github-actions

I wrote this CI for mu vue/nuxt application:

```yaml
name: test

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x, 16.x, 18.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'
      - run: npm ci --ignore-scripts
      - run: npx vitest --run
```

However I get this error just after dependencies are retrieved:

```bash
Run npm ci --ignore-scripts
  npm ci --ignore-scripts
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser

Error: The operation was canceled.
```

No log is provided and no error messages, only the action being cancelled

I would like to run a successful CI action to run my tests and lint my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be seeing that error from a job in the matrix because of another failing one.

In GitHub actions [`jobs.<job_id>.strategy.fail-fast`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategyfail-fast) is set by default to `true`. This means that GitHub will cancel all in-progress and queued jobs in the matrix if any job in the matrix fails.

In your case, you have a matrix running `npm ci --ignore-scripts` and `npx vitest --run`. Both steps can fail for different reasons and will cause the termination of all running jobs in the same matrix for the different Node.js versions in your case.

If `npm ci` is failing for you, check your `.npmrc` and proxy setup if you are using a private artifactory.

If not, try using `nvm use YOUR_NODE_VERSION`, delete `package-lock.json` then run `npm install` locally and let it rebuild your dependency tree.

Also, note that you should use a Node version that is compatible with your Nuxt/Vue tooling, or that's declared in [`package.json`'s engines](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#engines). So unless you are building a library that must be compatible with different Node.js/npm versions you might not need to support all 3 versions you specified in the matrix.

Comment: indeed, i tried to run the action locally with `act` and discovered that nuxt tsconfig was being missing in CI